PAC File isResolvable(host) vs dnsResolve(host)
I've been reading online and it says isResolvable(host) checks if the given hostname can be resolved to an IP address while dnsResolve(host) resolves the given hostname to its corresponding IP address(es).
I'm struggling to understand how the outcome of both functions are different as I would obtain an IP Address and I can configure my PAC File to route internal websites directly.
What are situations where one is better than the other? I dont think you can just use it interchangeably.
I tried using the two functions and I got the same results.
